# SQL for getting values before nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to find a query for getting values before nil.

In my database I have table with column called table_number. Usually values are incremented by 1 in this table when ever specific actions are made in code, like this

```
id, table_number
1   1 
2   2
3   3
4   nil
5   nil
6   nil
7   nil
8   nil
9   nil
10  nil
```

but now there is possibility that for specific record table number can be specified. So my question is how to keep incriminating values if there is already value specified. The scenario looks something like this:

```
id, table_number
1   1 
2   2
3   3
4   nil
5   nil
6   nil
7   nil
8   nil
9   6
10  nil
```

So right I guess thing here to do would be get all values that are not nil find one which are incremented by one and keep incriminating if the value is not specified. but how to do that, so table after all records have been filed looks like this:

```
id, table_number
1   1 
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   6
10  10
```

I am working on rails, but SQL would be fine too :) Thank you

Comment: Just set `table_number` to `id` if that is what you want.

Comment: well column ids can be different but table number always starts from 1

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment - not enough reputation - but I feel like the problem is potentially unsolvable unless you can guarantee that the id column is always going to be in a correct ascending order (even if it isn't starting at 1 - and even if it isn't always going up by 1).

If that is indeed the case, then perhaps you could do

```
DECLARE @firstNilId int;

SELECT @firstNilId = MIN(Id) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE table_number = 'nil' 

DECLARE @prevTableNum int;

SELECT TOP 1 @prevTableNum = table_number 
FROM mytable
WHERE Id < @firstNilId 
ORDER BY Id ASC 

UPDATE mytable 
SET table_number = @prevTableNum + 1 
WHERE Id = @firstNilId
```

I believe that this should give you what you are looking for. Please clarify if any of my assumptions were incorrect.

Thanks,
K

EDIT 1: I should point out that I haven't tested this. Just throwing that disclaimer out there. If somebody tries this, please share your findings. Thanks!